# How can I get the position of the cursor in a console app?

Tags: c#, console

I would like to be able to check that the position of the cursor hasn't moved past a certain point.  I haven't been able to find anything that gives the position of the text cursor via google.  I'm not really sure where else to look.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at the various methods and properties of the Console class.  Specifically, using Console.CursorLeft and Console.CursorTop, you can get and set the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 8):

Use Console.CursorLeft and Console.CursorTop

Please look at this MSDN link for more information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx